# pyEphem for calculting perfect moon position, using Lahiri ayanamsa

Tags: python-2.7, pyephem

I am looking PyEphem python module to find moon position with accuracy for astrological research

```
    import ephem
    'Setting Delhi as location with 77E12 longitude, 28:36 lattitude
    Delhi = ephem.Observer()
    Delhi.lon = ephem.degrees('77:12')
    Delhi.lon
    Delhi.lat = ephem.degrees('28:36')
    Delhi.date = '2015/3/22 9:00'
    'Finding moon position for Delhi for specific time
    m = ephem.Moon(Delhi)
    print m.ra, m.dec
    1:49:58.80 9:09:41.2
    print (ephem.constellation(m))
    ('Psc', 'Pisces')
```

This is a wrong answer

Expected Answer:
Aries, 01:32:12 from mykundali.com

Whether this ephem module take care of sidereal-time?
Please suggest me to match Moons position

Note:
If I subtract Lahiri Ayanamsa of 24 deg, Aries answer will come
But 01:32:12 can not be achieved

Answer (score 3):

The answer is coming out different because astrology does not pay attention to the real stars and constellations, but instead to unchanging 30°-wide segments of the celestial equator that it calls “houses.” So while PyEphem is correct that the Moon is in the constellation Pisces, you will instead want to simply take the Right Ascension and divide by 30° and then look up a table of which house belongs to 0–30°, which to 30–60°, and so forth.

The constellation boundaries used by astronomers and PyEphem, because they help us point our binoculars and telescopes at the sky, are not all 30° wide because they follow the actual outlines of the constellations:

http://pbarbier.com/constellations/con_capricorn.jpg